# Web Service Timeout for Java in CXF framework

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I am trying to set timeout for a web service in the CXF Framework. For that I am using the following code snippet

```
Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
httpClientPolicy.setReceiveTimeout(value); 
http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);
```

where the variable value contains the Response Timeout Value for that particular webservice.
My question is that if the web service times out, will the method throw a timed out exception? 
Do I get a non zero response code like the other times when a web service fails?

Comment: Did you try it, perhaps with a very low timeout?

Comment: I believe it would throw error rather than sending back response message.

Comment: You mean to say a timeout exception?

Comment: @Poulami SocketTimeOut Exception